# Thrift TMemoryBuffer Transport in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, thrift

We use thrift-generated data structures in several languages. C++, python, C#, Lua, and Java have buffer implementations of Transport, but I can't find one in javascript or typescript. In fact, the comments in the js source say

> The JavaScript Transport object type uses Http[s]/XHR and is the sole browser based Thrift transport.

Many of our use cases do not involve client-server communication, so this ain't gonna work.

So is there a way around this, or does anybody have a memory buffer TTransport implementation in js or ts?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question.  Are you talking about `TMemoryTransport`?  Because that would only work if your service provider were in the same process as your client.  Is that your case?  Is your service provider also in JS?

I suppose I'm just confused by what a "buffer implementation of transport" is.  Are you talking about a raw TCP transport?  A file transport?

Comment: I mean TMemoryBuffer

Comment: It does not appear such a module exists (https://thrift.apache.org/docs/Languages) but it shouldn't be hard to create one using NodeJS's builtin `Buffer` or (https://github.com/feross/buffer) if you need browser support.